# It starts the boot image (usplash) KDE/Lubuntu in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, lubuntu, system

When installing KDE / Lubuntu in Ubuntu 12.04 system startup has changed (artwork). How I can regain Ubuntu boot image files without uninstalling Lubuntu? (Because I have Lubuntu you ever apatece I use it).

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu no longer uses usplash as it now uses Plymouth.

To restore Ubuntu start up theme you need to uninstall the KDE/Lubuntu themes.

```
sudo apt-get remove plymouth-theme-lubuntu-logo
sudo apt-get remove plymouth-theme-kubuntu-logo
```

That should do it.

If not run

```
sudo apt-get install plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo
```

Hope this helps someone.